# Excel Pivot functionality

Tags: excel, pivot

Is there a way to remove the aggregate values that appear in the collapsed form in Pivot rows?
Please see the attached screenshot.
I dont want the Sum of the values that appear against a Name if the Row is in collapsed form. I have already selected "Do not show subtotals" but that doesnt remove this. Only when we expand the field, then the values on the header row disappear.

[image]

Comment: I think you need to remove the Field you are using for VALUE ,,, this will not allow PT do display numeric data & aggregate function applied on it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While this doesn't address the specific question, you could change the report layout to Tabular form. Your PT will look like this, where the 2nd named field is empty when collapsed. That may help someone identify when to ignore the numeric columns.

[image]

To better identify when to ignore those numeric values, you could also add conditional formatting to the numeric columns (C and D in this case).

1. Highlight the entire pivot column C and then go to Conditional Formatting... New Rule... Rule Type "Use a formula to determine which cells to format".
2. In the formula bar within the conditional formatting popup, type: =isblank(b4)
3. Click on the Format button.
4. Here you can decide to format the font or cell. Pick a format you want, such as a Gray cell.
5. Repeat steps above for column D.

Here, I choose a gray cell for Column C, and white text for Column D. Column D looks blank when collapsed, but it's really not.

Here's how the PT will look:

[image]